# Simultaniously run three Powerpoint presentations

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, microsoft-powerpoint

I recently swapped three Powerpoint-presentation computers with one multi-display computer. Reason is allocation cost, energy cost and to simplify the administration when changing presentations each week.

The problem is that Powerpoint 2010/2013 doesn't seem to be designed for the job. I want to run three individual animated presentations. One per monitor on the same computer at the same time.

My thought is if its possible to use three virtual machines and autostarting RDP to each VM, which use Powerpoint as shell, pointing towards a folder where I upload new slides whenever required.

Are there any alternatives to my idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an idea, export the slides and run three different browser windows or whatever else PP exports to? Unless of course there is need for native app control and presentation perfection.

Comment: I haven't used it personally, but some of the commercial but low-cost software from Chirag Dalal at http://officeone.mvps.org will probably do the job for you.  @arch-abit has a good suggestion too.  You can't export HTML from PPT 2013; the feature's gone.  You can from 2010 with a bit of VBA, though there's no user interface for it.

Comment: The PowerShow add-in did the trick. ~$100 is an OK price in my opinion. Thanks!